# Count frequency of substring in multiple columns, get column names of positive results

Tags: python, pandas

I have some sequencing data of multiple patients in pandas dataframe, each patient has one column with genotype (string in format x/x:xxx:xxxx), the number of patients will vary...
I need to do two things with this information,

1. count frequency of substrings in each genotype column for each row e.g. three patients with genotype: 0/1:xxx:xxxx 0/1:xxxx:xxxx 1/1:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx and I need to get how many times was 0/1 in row into new column df['freq_01'], how many times was 1/1 in row into df['freq_11'] etc.
2. I would need to create new column with sample names (name of the column) for each genotype from previous step like:
   df['samples_01]= "S1, S2, S4" (for each row)

I am able to do this by iterating over each row, but I wonder if it is possible to do that by pandas more efficiently.

The original data (in my file there is about 100 000 rows):

```
| id | S1      | S2      | S3      | S4      |
|----|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| 1  | 1/1:5:5 | 0/1:3:3 | 0/1:2:2 | 0/1:7:6 |
| 2  | 0/1:3:3 | 1/1:5:5 | 1/1:5:5 | 0       |
| 3  | 0/1:3:3 | 0       | 0/1:3:3 | 1/1:5:5 |
```

How should look the result:

```
| id | S1      | S2      | S3      | S4      | freq_01 | samples_01 |
|----|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|------------|
| 1  | 1/1:5:5 | 0/1:3:3 | 0/1:2:2 | 0/1:7:6 | 3       | S2,S3,S4   |
| 2  | 0/1:3:3 | 1/1:5:5 | 1/1:5:5 | 0       | 1       | S1         |
| 3  | 0/1:3:3 | 0       | 0/1:3:3 | 1/1:5:5 | 2       | S1,S3      |
```

Comment: It could be easier to answer if you showed what the initial data is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Series.str.startswith()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) to convert dataframe into an array of all boolean values and then count the frequency and find the column names having True values on each row. Below is a sample code:

```
#get a list of columns names required in calculation
cols = df.filter(like='S').columns
#Index(['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4'], dtype='object')

# set up an array with True/False using Series.str.startswith
arr_01 = np.array([ df[c].str.startswith('0/1:') for c in cols ]).T
print(arr_01)
#array([[False,  True,  True,  True],
#       [ True, False, False, False],
#       [ True, False,  True, False]])

# count the True value on row
df['freq_01'] = np.sum(arr_01, axis=1)

# retrieve column names with True values only
df['samples_01'] = [ ','.join(filter(len, x)) for x in np.multiply(arr_01, np.array(cols)) ]
print(df)
#   id       S1       S2       S3       S4  freq_01  samples_01
#0   1  1/1:5:5  0/1:3:3  0/1:2:2  0/1:7:6        3    S2,S3,S4
#1   2  0/1:3:3  1/1:5:5  1/1:5:5        0        1          S1
#2   3  0/1:3:3        0  0/1:3:3  1/1:5:5        2       S1,S3
```

To handle more cases, just use a *for* loop:

```
cols = df.filter(like='S').columns

for t in [ '01', '11' ]:
    subt = t[0] + '/' + t[1] + ':'
    arr_t = np.array([ df[c].str.startswith(subt) for c in cols ]).T
    df['freq_{}'.format(t)] = np.sum(arr_t, axis=1)
    df['samples_{}'.format(t)] = [ ','.join(filter(len, x)) for x in np.multiply(arr_t, np.array(cols)) ]

print(df)
#   id       S1       S2       S3       S4  freq_01  freq_11  samples_01 samples_11
#0   1  1/1:5:5  0/1:3:3  0/1:2:2  0/1:7:6        3        1    S2,S3,S4         S1
#1   2  0/1:3:3  1/1:5:5  1/1:5:5        0        1        2          S1      S2,S3
#2   3  0/1:3:3        0  0/1:3:3  1/1:5:5        2        1       S1,S3         S4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use:

```
df['S1'].str.count(':')
```

---

Which will count the substrings ":" in column S1

```
   id       S1       S2       S3       S4  freq_01 samples_01
0   1  1/1:5:5  0/1:3:3  0/1:2:2  0/1:7:6        3   S2,S3,S4
1   2  0/1:3:3  1/1:5:5  1/1:5:5        0        1         S1
2   3  0/1:3:3        0  0/1:3:3  1/1:5:5        2      S1,S3

0    2
1    2
2    2
Name: S1, dtype: int64
```

For `samples_01` column to count the number of comma separated elements use this:

```
df['samples_01'].str.count(',')+1

0    3
1    1
2    2
Name: samples_01, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas works better with columns so I will assume that the initial data is close to the tranpose of what you have shown:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1: {'S1': '1/1:5:5', 'S2': '0/1:3:3', 'S3': '0/1:2:2', 'S4': '0/1:7:6'},
                   2: {'S1': '0/1:3:3', 'S2': '1/1:5:5', 'S3': '1/1:5:5', 'S4': '0'},
                   3: {'S1': '0/1:3:3', 'S2': '0', 'S3': '0/1:3:3', 'S4': '1/1:5:5'}}
                  ).rename_axis('id', axis=1)
```

it prints as:

```
id        1        2        3
S1  1/1:5:5  0/1:3:3  0/1:3:3
S2  0/1:3:3  1/1:5:5        0
S3  0/1:2:2  1/1:5:5  0/1:3:3
S4  0/1:7:6        0  1/1:5:5
```

Then for each *value* to process, I will build a temporary dataframe to know whether the value is present. For example for `'0/1'`:

```
temp = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.match('0/1'))
```

gives:

```
id      1      2      3
S1  False   True   True
S2   True  False  False
S3   True  False   True
S4   True  False  False
```

It is then easy to find the frequency and list of samples:

```
freq0_1 = temp.agg(lambda x: x[x].count()).rename('freq_01')
samples0_1 = temp.agg(lambda x: list(x[x].index)).rename('samples0_1')
```

If you want to process multiple possible values, it is still simple:

```
series = []
for value, ident in [('0/1', '01'), ('1/1', '11')]:
    temp = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.match(value))
    freq = temp.agg(lambda x: x[x].count()).rename('freq_' + ident)
    samples = temp.agg(lambda x: list(x[x].index)).rename('samples_' + ident)
    series.extend([freq, samples])

print(pd.concat(series, axis=1))
```

gives:

```
   freq_01    samples_01 freq_11 samples_11
id                                         
1        3  [S2, S3, S4]       1       [S1]
2        1          [S1]       2   [S2, S3]
3        2      [S1, S3]       1       [S4]
```